# How to submit a spark python job via a rest api call

Tags: apache-spark

I know we can submit a jar via [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)
,but we have lots of jobs written in python ,I want to know how we can submit a python job or an egg file through a  rest api call

Comment: welcome to SO, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

They have created documentation for python support

*- Full documentation how to create python job - [spark-jobserver Python Support Reference](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/python.md)*

> Spark Job Server supports Python jobs through a Python specific context factory `spark.jobserver.python.PythonSparkContextFactory`.

Like you noticed you need to package python spark job.

> In order to be able to push a job to the the job server, it must be packaged into a Python Egg file.

Firstly you need to create context with HTTP POST /contexts/application-name context with "Python factory".

> `curl -X POST 'localhost:8090/contexts/py-context?context-factory=spark.jobserver.python.PythonSparkContextFactory'`

- After successfully created context you have to package a job. They suggest use setuptools - check [Packaging a job](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/python.md#packaging-a-job)).
- After packaging job you need to upload your egg file using eg. curl.

> `curl --data-binary @dist/my_job_package-0.0.0-py2.7.egg \
>   -H 'Content-Type: application/python-archive' localhost:8090/binaries/my_py_job`

If this step is done you can check whether job was successfully started using spark-jobserver job API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Livy](https://livy.apache.org/) (A REST Service for Apache Spark)

1. You need to create a pyspark session:

`curl -X POST --data '{"kind": "pyspark"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8998/sessions`

2. Submit your code:

`curl localhost:8998/sessions/0/statements -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"code":"sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).count()"}'`

[Documentation](https://livy.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html)